# Drop packet recieved from network using python (scapy?)

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I am creating a program in python (either 2 or 3) in which I need to be able to drop a packet. Using scapy I know how to inspect packets, craft one and modify one sniffed from the sniff() function. I believe the sniff function can't actually modify the incomming packets (correct me if I'm wrong). I would like to know how I could drop some packets. Ex: if it has a src.ip==192.168.1.5, then drop it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not drop packets with scapy or any other sniffing programm.
You should try using iptables. There is a wrapper for iptables called [python-iptables](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables). It can help you to create, manage and delete different firewall rules from your python programm

Comment: If you wonder why the packets cannot be dropped: The software does not intercept the traffic, it instead shares a view on the network data through promiscuous mode.